# Line Break in string for PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
$bodyString = "$address\r\n\n\n$country\r\n\n\n$experience\r\n\n\n$message";
$mail->Subject = "$name : $email";
$mail->Body = $bodyString;
```

I m trying these \n to break the line but instead of getting line break I m getting spaces. 
 not working.

Given below is body I m getting in Mail

```
123 123 132 321
```

Comment: Some email clients *condense* line breaks.

Comment: Are you sending plain text or HTML mail?

Comment: Stick to one kind of line break - use `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`, but don't mix them up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This way](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl2br.asp) insert line breaks where newlines (\n) occur in the string:

```
<?php
    $bodyString =  nl2br("$address\n\n\n\n$country\n\n\n\n$experience\n\n\n\n$message");
?>
```

Comment: and don't mix break types to start with.

Comment: @Synchro You are totally true. I edited the answer. Tnx.